# Extend XML Schema enumeration without changing files using it

Tags: xml, xsd

I've got a lot of XML schemas, let's say a.xsd, b.xsd, c.xsd which contains element types that make use of an enumeration for some of their attributes.

So imagine that somewhere in the definition of these types there is:

```
<xsd:attribute name="attr1" type="MyEnum" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
```

Now I need to add some values to this enumeration, but I cannot touch the enumeration definition as that definition should be kept as it is because it is part of a standard.

How can I extend it using another XSD schema WITHOUT changing references in a.xsd, b.xsd and c.xsd?
I would like to kind of redefine this Enumeration in a way that everywhere is referenced the new one is used instead of the old one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In theory, this can be achieved using xsd:redefine. The problem is though how do you want to use this redefined value? It may be that your tool doesn't support redefines. It would help if you could provide more info on your scenario, from an end to end perspective.